# how to use module = __import__(filename) and invoke the main function

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to develop this program , that invokes the main function of another program and takes the program to be inkoved's name as user input , let us call this program 1 :

Program 1  # takes the program 2's name as user input

```
try:

    print "Please input the file you want to test"
    filename = raw_input().split(".")[0]
    module = __import__(filename)

except:
```

program 2 is like

```
def main():
    first()

def first():
    5/0

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

so basically I want to know how to invoke program 2's main function from program 1 .

thank you

Comment: Try `import`ing the other file.

Comment: module = __import__(filename) does exactly that

Comment: I meant by using the `import` statement. In either case, you can treat it like a regular module; I don't see where the issue lies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do `module.main()` - there's nothing special about a function called `main`